# How to Find Work In a Sports Research Room

Tags: history, statistics, media

I have had a passion and love of history and statistics since childhood and it is a goal of mine to work in a research room. How does one do this? It does not seems as though ESPN and other networks advertise such positions. What should I do or who should I contact to make my goal a reality? I am interested in working in research rooms such as those used during the Olympics, Grand Slam tennis tournaments, and the World Cup.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about finding work.

Comment: I don't think this question is a complete lost-cause. If it was edited to ask about what sort of background sports statisticians have (in terms of education) and how they're recruited, I think it can be on topic. The focus at the moment seems purely vocational, which would make it a much better fit for [The Workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @studro It's already there http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/36197/how-to-find-work-in-a-sports-research-room